# Dockerfile Entrypoint issue

Tags: python, bash, docker, flask, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile to create an image of a Python Flask application:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
COPY ./requirements.txt /appFlask/requirements.txt
COPY . /appFlask

WORKDIR /appFlask

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 mainPage:app" ]
```

It builds fine except for the last step, which gives me the following error:

ERROR: standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory

It is so simple that I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Also, is there a better base image than python:3.7-slim-buster to build lightweight flask images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If `bash` is not in the path, you'll need to supply the full path
2. If you want to pass a command to bash, the syntax is `bash -c "my whole script"`, which in docker will become:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "my whole script"]
```

3. Bonus: why not use gunicorn itself as the entrypoint? Why bother with bash?

Answer (score 3):

The entrypoint should be:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-b, "0.0.0.0:5000", "mainPage:app" ]
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 mainPage:app
```

src: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: IMO his answer is actually better since it's more generic. my answer is just for your specific case.